# HTTP long poll client

Tags: http, go, httpclient, long-polling

I'm implementing a HTTP long poll client in Go for receiving updates from a [server](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/native#updating-certificates-and-certificate-roots).
What's the difference in normal HTTP client and Long-poll client in Go?
It is just the timeout?

My code looks like this:

```
request, err := http.NewRequest(get, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Error")
        return
    }
    request.Header.Set(consulTokenHeader, aclToken)
    httpClient := &http.Client{} //introduce timeout?
    response, err := httpClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: "long-poll" is a made up term: every http request has a corresponding response (or transport level error). End of story.

Comment: There is no difference. "Long-poll" is a technique, not a type of client or type of request.